# give control in datalist color

Tags: c#

I had datalist as menu that display categories and subs and I want to give red color or css for the selected item(category or sub)
 I tried but I had a problem 
This is my code

```
 private  Label Lb;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
```

protected void dlCategory_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)

```
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
         Lb = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("LblCat");

    }


}



protected void dlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        Lb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need more details. You did not describe what problem you're facing.

Is `Lb` object null after this code?
`Lb = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("LblCat");`

Is there any exception thrown? Is yes, what is the message?

Comment: the control lb=null
and when i made breakpoints it didn't go to 
protected void dlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        Lb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;


}

Comment: I feel that since you cannot find the correct label, the object being returned is null.
You should then introduce this code in dlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged:-  if(Lb != null) { Lb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; } This will avoid throwing up of exception.
As far as finding the label is concerned, either the key being passed to FindControl is incorrect or Item doesn't contain the label.

Comment: I did that But compiler not compile this code 

 protected void dlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Lb != null)
        {
            Lb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }